# When does one pronounce the 's' in plus?

Tags: prononciation, négation, comparatifs

When a friend of mine asked why so many contractors worked in Dubai, I replied by saying (approximately):

> À Dubai, on a plus d'argent.

Meaning to say that one can earn more money in Dubai.  I pronounced the "plus" in this phrase: /ply/ (rhymes with "stew" in English).  My friend looked puzzled and after a while said:

> Tu veux dire, on a plus d'argent!

At least, that's what it sounded like to me.  Except he pronounced the 's' in "plus": /plys/ (rhymes with "juice" in English).

I thought the sounding of the 's' was optional.  Clearly I'm wrong!  :)  Can someone please explain the difference between /ply/ and /plys/?

Comment: Note also that "We don't have any money anymore" would also be *written* differently: "On n'a plus d'argent" and not "On a plus d'argent".

Comment: By the way, the "s" in "moins" (less) is sometimes pronounced, and sometimes not (depending on the region).

Comment: @Raphink: So in "On n'a plus d'argent" would **not** pronounce the 's'?

Comment: @alpian, exact. Otherwise you would probably be misunderstood.

Comment: @Raphink: Note that this is not necessarily true in highly informal contexts. In a chat room, "on a plus d'argent" is perfectly ambiguous because it could just as well mean "on n'a plus d'argent" !

Comment: @Brennan: right :-) I was only referring to properly written French :-)

Comment: This may be irrelevant, since your concern is about the 's', but HOW is /ply/ supposed to rhyme with 'stew' (/stu/) or /plys/ with 'juice' (/dʒuːs/) ?

Comment: @SaschaRambeaud Because native English speakers often can't initially hear or pronounce the difference between /y/ and /u/ in French pronunciation. :)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Il y a trois mots qui s'écrivent « [plus](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plus) ».

1. Une particule **négative**, utilisée pour nier quelque chose qui était vrai dans le passé mais ne l'est pas maintenant.

   > Je n'ai plus d'argent, je suis ruiné. (*I have no more money, I'm ruined.*)

   On ne prononce **jamais** le `s` (donc : `[ply]`), sauf pour faire la liaison (`[plyz]`).

   > Je ne suis plus aussi rapide qu'avant. (lit. *I am no longer as quick as before.*, trad. *I am not as quick as I used to be*) `[…plyzosi…]`

   Comme avec les autres particules négatives, on peut omettre la particule *ne* en langage familier. Dans des contextes informels, *plus* dans ce sens est quelquefois prononcé `py`.

   > J'ai plus `[py]` d'argent, j'suis `[ʃɥi]` fauché. (*I have no more money, I'm skint.*)
2. Un adverbe (et nom) qui signale une addition. Il y a plusieurs sous-cas.

   - Lorsque « plus » est un **adverbe**, on ne prononce **en principe pas** le `s` : `[ply]`, sauf encore pour faire la liaison (`[plyz]`). Toutefois, lorsqu'il y a un **risque de confusion**, on prononce le `s` sourd (`[plys]`). C'est justement le cas dans ton exemple : « On a plus d'argent » (« *we have more money* ») serait indistinguable à l'oral de « on n'a plus d'argent » qui a le sens exactement opposé, donc on dit `[ɔ̃naplysdargɑ̃]`. On prononce aussi souvent le `s` sourd **en fin** de phrase ou de groupe de mots suffisamment autonome : « de plus en plus » (« *more and more* ») `[dəplyzɑ̃plys]`.
   - « Plus » sert en particulier à former un comparatif ou un superlatif.

     > Il est plus grand que moi. (*He is taller than me.*)
     >   L'Everest est la montagne la plus haute. (*Mount Everest is the tallest mountain.*)

     On prononce rarement le `s` (hors liaison), mais ça peut arriver pour insister lorsqu'on pense qu'il y a un risque de confusion.
   - Dans un usage **mathématique**, on prononce le `s` sourd. « Deux plus deux » (« *two and two* ») `[døplysdø]`.
   - Lorsque « plus » est un **nom**, on prononce le `s` sourd.

     > Qui peut le plus peut le moins. (proverbe, lit. « *Who can do the most can do the least* ») `[kipøləplyspøləmwɛ̃]`
     >   D'autant plus que ... (*all the more as …*) `[dotɑ̃plyskə]`
3. Une forme conjuguée du verbe « **plaire** » (passé simple). On ne prononce pas le `s` (sauf liaison).

---

There are three words in French which are spelled *[plus](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plus)*. The first two form a duality which is similar to the English *more*.

1. A **negative** particle (to go with *ne* except in colloquial speech, like any other negation). “*Ne … plus*” indicates that something is no longer true, i.e. that it is not true now but by implication it was true at some point in the past.

   > Je n'ai plus d'argent, je suis ruiné. (*I have no more money, I'm ruined.*)

   The `s` is **always silent** (thus `[ply]`) except when a [liaison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)) is required, in which case the word is pronounced `[ply.z]`.

   > Je ne suis plus aussi rapide qu'avant. (lit. *I am no longer as quick as before.*, idiomatically *I am not as quick as I used to be*) `[…plyzosi…]`.

   In colloquial speech, in addition to omitting *ne* (which is very common), the `[l]` sound is sometimes skipped.

   > J'ai plus `[py]` d'argent, j'suis `[ʃɥi]` fauché. (*I have no more money, I'm skint.*)
2. An adverb (and occasional noun) which denotes an addition, There are several sub-cases.

   - When *plus* is an **adverb**, the `s` is **generally silent**: `[ply]`, except as before for a liaison (`[plyz]`). However, **when there is a potential confusion**, the `s` is sounded, always voicelessly (`[plys]`). Your example falls squarely into this case: “*on a plus d'argent*” (“we have more money”) would be indistinguishable from “*on n'a plus d'argent*” which has the opposite meaning, hence it would be pronounced `[ɔ̃naplysdargɑ̃]`. The voiceless `s` is also usually sounded **at the end** of a sentence or sufficiently autonomous phrase, such as “*de plus en plus*” (“more and more”) `[dəplyzɑ̃plys]`.
   - The adverb *plus* can in particular be used to indicate a comparative or a superlative.

     > Il est plus grand que moi. (*He is taller than me.*)
     >   L'Everest est la montagne la plus haute. (*Mount Everest is the tallest mountain.*)

     In this case, the `s` is rarely sounded (liaisons excepted), but it can happen when the speaker fears that there is a risk of confusion and wishes to insist.
   - In **mathematical** usage, the `s` is always voiceless, never silent.

     > Deux plus deux (*two and two*) `[døplysdø]`
   - When *plus* is a **noun**, the `s` is always voiceless, never silent.

     > Qui peut le plus peut le moins. (proverb, lit. *Who can do the most can do the least*) `[kipøləplyspøləmwɛ̃]`
     >   D'autant plus que ... (*all the more as …*) `[dotɑ̃plyskə]`
3. The simple past (second or third person singular) of the verb ***plaire***. The `s` is always silent (except in a liaison).

Comment: Id say "I have no money left" instead of "no more money" which sounds awkward to me).

Comment: (For non native speakers: note that in the spoken language, the "ne" is omitted more often than not. So pronouncing plus wrong will cause speakers to hear the opposite of what you intend, as happened to the OP.)

Comment: Not sure if @ tags work cross-answer, so @Gille can you respond to my comment on the answer below this? I am confused by the answers being contradictory yet both having a large number of upvotes.

Comment: @Aerovistae Cédric's answer isn't contradictory. It doesn't discuss all the cases, only the two main ones: my 1 = no more → silent, my 2 = more → sometimes sounded.

Comment: « Je ne suis plus aussi rapide qu'avant. » Notons que la liaison est ici facultative, car il n’y a pas d’ambiguïté sur la nature du mot…

Les cas difficiles entre "plus" et "plus" apparaissent justement à l’écrit, car on ne peut pas différencier avec une liaison… À tel point qu’on peut rencontrer le caractère '+' pour lever toute ambiguïté dans une phrase.

Answer (score 26):

In a short way :

- you pronounce the 's' when "plus" means more.
- you don't pronounce the 's' when "plus" means no more.

Comment: Yet you don't pronounce it in _"pas plus tard qu'hier"_

Comment: (+1) Thanks!  This is a great and simple explanation for an easy concept that has always puzzled me!

Comment: This at odds with @Gille 's answer, whose #2 bullet suggests your first rule is not correct.

Comment: @Aerovistae I just tried to make a simple answer with general rules and that was related to the OP, Gilles's answer is much more detailled and explain many other cases, but not clearly contradictory

Answer (score 10):

The 's' pronunciation can help to make the difference between the "plus" used a as negation (/ply/)

> "Je n'ai plus d'argent" =~ "Je n'ai pas d'argent"
>
> "I have no more money" =~ "I have no money"
>
> "Je ne fais plus cela" =~ "Je ne fais pas cela"
>
> "I don't do this anymore" =~ "I do not do this"

The /plys/ version is used to refer to the additive operator `+`.

> "J'ai plus d'argent que toi" ~ "I have more money than you"
>
> "Je n'ai pas plus d'argent que toi" ~ "I do not have more money than you"
>
> "Je n'ai pas plus d'information pour toi" ~ "I have no more(additional) information for you"

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the detailed explanation and examples - I think I get it now! :)

Answer (score 4):

You'll also want to pay attention to the `[plyz]` pronunciation when *plus* is followed by a vowel.

See http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/plus.htm for more information and exercises. Notice exercises 7 and 8 are very close to your example.

Funnily enough, [the cnrtl doesn't seem to list any other pronunciation than `[ply]`](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/plus)

Answer (score 4):

You pronounce the 's' when is the notion of additional amount, addition, supplement, more.

You don't pronounce the 's' when is a concept of quantity, but reduced to zero, nothing, or no more.

- **Listen audio prononciation :** http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/plus.htm
- **Source :** http://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=33919&titre=prononciation+de+plus%3F

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I mostly just wanted to give Gilles a bounty for a really magnificent explanation up top there, but this is a solid answer too.