# Does “ne même plus” mean “no more” or “no more than”?

Tags: sens, négation, comparatifs, adverbes

I'm reading a novel, here is a paragraph from it:

> Aujourd'hui elle ne lui demande plus rien. Depuis la naissance de Selma ils n'ont même plus d'intimité physique. Pourtant elle ne croit pas qu'il lui soit infidèle; au lieu d'en être satisfaite, elle l'en méprise, mettant sa fidélité sur le compte de sa nonchalance. Leurs relations ont le goût d'un verre d'eau tiède. Mais Hatidjé a dépassé le temps de la nostalgie.

Oh, here Selma is Hatidjé's daughter.

For the 2nd sentence, does it mean

- Since the birth of Selma, they have no more physical intimacy. or,
- Since the birth of Selma, they have no more than physical intimacy. (means only physical intimacy but no affection)

?

Sorry I'm a bit lost by the “ne … que” locution in French…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first proposal is quite close. More precisely, “*Ils n'ont plus d'intimité*” would be “they don't have intimacy anymore”. If you add “*même*” it means “they don't even have intimacy anymore”.

Exact translations are a bit difficult, but to add something to the picture consider the following correspondances:

- They don't have more intimacy ↔ *Ils n'ont pas plus d'intimité (qu'avant)*
- They have no more than intimacy ↔ *Ils n'ont rien de plus que l'intimité*

Comment: @athos: Also, you can have a look to this [question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/268/79), originally about pronunciation, to have a better understanding about the strange case of *plus* and *plus* being homonyms.

Comment: *Ils n'ont rien de plus que l'intimité* semble vraiment étrange (au niveau du sens). Que pourrait bien signifier n'avoir plus que l'intimité ?