# How does "plus" makes the sentence negative?

Tags: grammaire, sens, négation

I'm pretty new to the French language and just saw the following line in the song "alors on danse" by Stromae;

*"alors tu t'bouches plus les oreilles"*

I know that "se boucher les oreilles" means to plug up/cover one's ears, but the sentence mean "So you *stop* covering your ears". How exactly does "plus" made it negative?

Comment: See also [When does one pronounce the 's' in plus?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/268/when-does-one-pronounce-the-s-in-plus).

Comment: *"Je t'aime plus."* Means nearly opposite things, depending on whether on pronounces the final *s*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The grammatically correct sentence is :

> *alors tu ne te bouches plus les oreilles*

**ne** is often omitted in the spoken language when using the negation form.

**ne plus** literally means **not anymore / stop.**

Comment: Oh right, he does that in the beggining also. So I just need to get used to "ne" being omitted.

Comment: and note that in some occasion, you need the context to understand the meaning of it, especially when written but sometimes also even when speaking, if the "s" is silent. Example: "J'en veux plus" could mean "I don't want anymore of it" (silent "s") or "I want more of this" (pronounced "s")

Comment: That's so much easier now thanks! I just thought it was one thing to omit "ne" if you still have its other end like "pas" or "rien", but with "plus" it could literally mean the opposite. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents :

J'en veux = I want (some of) it

J'en veux plus = I want more of it (s pronounced)

Je n'en veux pas = I don't want (any of) it

Je n'en veux plus = I don't want anymore of it (s not pronounced)

Answer (score 2):

It is worth adding that *plus* is pronounced differently when it is a part of negation (pronounced as *plu*) and when it means *more* (pronounced as *plusse*). Thus, even when the negation particle *ne* is omitted, the following two sentences do not sound the same:
*Je (ne) t'aime plus* (I don't love you anymore.)
vs.
*Je t'aime plus (qu'avant.)* (I love you more (than before.))

Comment: j'aurais écrit *plus (qu'avant)* plutôt que *plus (que avant)*.