# Pronunciation of "ne ... plus de + noun"

Tags: prononciation, négation

> I don't want any more milk.

I think the translation should be

> Je ne veux plus de lait.

Is *plus* here pronounced with or without the *s*? I know that in general it is pronounced without the *s* in negations, but with the *s* when it is followed by *de* and a noun. In this case, which rule applies?

Comment: [When does one pronounce the 's' in plus?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/268/when-does-one-pronounce-the-s-in-plus)

Comment: @Andreas I don't see the case "plus de" in that link.

Comment: It's case 1.  in the accepted answer  (negative particle).

Comment: You pronounce the 's' in 'plus' when there's a positive connotation of 'more'. "tu en veux plus (plooss)?" " do you want any more?" . To be distinguished from "tu n'en veux plus (ploo)?" " you won't want any more?" - sorry struggling foreigners :-) but so the 's' or not adds to your chances of understanding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Je ne veux [ploo] de lait.

Since it has a negative context.
[[Read more here]](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-pronounce-plus-french-adverb-4084872)

Comment: What does [ploo] mean? It's neither a word nor the pronunciation of a word. Anyway the answer to the question had already been given  on FL as pointed out in @Andreas's comment above.

Comment: C'est vrai qu'on ne prononce pas le "s", mais "ploo"? "Plu" ou en IPA "ply"