# Prononciation de "plus" dans "il y a plus d'un an"

Tags: prononciation, adverbes

Selon cette [règle](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/270/11550) simple, on prononce le *s* dans *plus* quand le mot a un sens positif, et non pas quand il a un sens négatif.

Pourtant, je viens d'écouter dans un journal télévisé l'expression

> il y a plus d'un an

où clairement le *s* n'est pas prononcé. Est-ce une exception de la règle ?

**Révision**: Laure a remarqué que le *s* n'est pas prononcé car il s'agit d'un comparatif. Je comprends que le *s* n'est pas prononcé quand *plus* est suivi par un adjectif:

> Je suis plus grand que toi.

mais j'ai pensé qu'il est prononcé quand *plus* est suivi de *de*:

> J'ai plus d'argent que toi.

Est-ce que j'ai tort ici ?

Comment: @Laure J'ai pensé que le *s* est prononcé quand *plus* est suivi de *de*, même s'il agit d'un comparatif, comme dans *J'ai plus d'argent que toi*. Est-ce que j'ai tort ?

Comment: Mon commentaire de hier était nul, il était tard, j'étais fatigué - pas une bonne excuse mais, bon...) je vais le supprimer.

Comment: Donc je disais que je disais une bêtise, *plus* dans *il y a plus d'un an* plus n'est pas un comparatif bien sûr. C'est tout simplement un adverbe. Tu as mal compris quand tu dis « on prononce le `s` dans plus quand le mot a un sens positif, et non pas quand il a un sens négatif. »  parce que tu renvoies à la réponse incomplète. Regarde la réponse acceptée : « Lorsque « plus » est un adverbe, on ne prononce en principe pas le `s` : [ply], sauf encore pour faire la liaison ([plyz]). »