# Prononciation de “plus” dans “de plus en plus”

Tags: prononciation

Je viens d'entendre l'expression

> de plus en plus nombreux

dans un journal télévisé, où le *s* dans le deuxième *plus* n'est pas prononcé. La [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/275/11550) ici dit au contraire que le deuxième *s* dans *de plus en plus* est souvent prononcé.

Alors, est-ce qu'il n'est pas prononcé dans l'expression ci-dessus parce qu'il est suivi de l'adjectif *nombreux* ? Où est-ce tout simplement facultatif ?

Comment: Quand on dit « de plus en plus nombreux » *plus* n'est **pas** en fin de groupe de mots autonome, donc on ne prononce pas le *s*.  Comme le dit [la réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/275/358) : « On prononce aussi souvent le s sourd en fin de phrase ou de groupe de mots **suffisamment autonome** : « De plus en plus » (« more and more ») [dəplyzɑ̃plys].  ».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectivement, le deuxième "s" n'est pas prononcé car il est suivi de "nombreux". On ne le prononcera pas non plus dans "j'ai de plus en plus mal", "elle est de plus en plus grande".

Par contre on entendra le "s" (prononcé comme un "z") dans "j'ai de plus en plus envie" ou "c'est de plus en plus agréable".

On peut donc dire que la liaison s'effectue en fonction du mot suivant pour que ce soit plus agréable à l'oreille.

A noter que si le deuxième "plus" termine l'expression, on prononcera son "s" (comme un "s", pas un "z") : "il m'en faut de plus en plus", "je l'aime de plus en plus".

Comment: est-il considéré comme une erreur de ne pas prononcer le "s" en fin d'expression. Je le prononce généralement moi-même, mais j'avoue que ca ne me choque pas particulièrement quand d'autres ne le font pas; En tout cas pas autant que quand on le prononce au milieu d'une expression, ce qui est parfois le cas chez les non-francophones.

Comment: En y réfléchissant, ça ne me choque pas non plus et on peut entendre les deux versions. Je ne sais pas maintenant s'il y a une véritable règle sur ce sujet...