# When is "ne" allowed to be deleted in "ne .. plus"?

Tags: grammaire, négation

In the following comic that showed up on my facebook feed, the child says

> J'en veux plus!

which I thought meant "I want more of it!". But as I continued to read the rest of the comic, I realized that it must have meant "I don't want more of it!"

[image: J'en veux plus comic]

Questions:

1) If "J'en veux plus" means "I don't want more of it!", then how do I say "I want more of it!"?

2) What are the rules for when I'm allowed to delete the "ne" in "ne .. pas"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) If "J'en veux plus" means "I don't want more of it!", then how do I say "I want more of it!"?

As Luke commented, *je n'en veux plus/j'en veux plus* is better translated to "I don't wan't it anymore". Your sentence would be *je n'en veux pas plus*.

"I want more of it" translation can be written exactly the same way: *j'en veux plus*, but is pronounced differently. The final **s** of *plu**s*** is sounded. See [When does one pronounce the 's' in plus?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/268/when-does-one-pronounce-the-s-in-plus)

Alternatively, you might say *j'en voudrais davantage* or *j'en veux encore*.

> 2) What are the rules for when I'm allowed to delete the "ne" in "ne .. pas"?

You can drop it in non-formal spoken French.

Comment: Rather than make another answer, I suggest adding: (a) It doesn't mean "I don't want more of it" but "I don't want it anymore." (b) Other ways to say "I want more of it."

Comment: To make sure I understand you: if I only showed you the first panel of the comic, is it true that it is completely ambiguous which is being said?

Comment: It is unambiguous because of the mother's reply.

Comment: @jlliagre Unless of course the toddler reasons like the [Mad Hatter](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rgs/alice-VII.html): "You can always have more than nothing!" ;) Kidding, of course...