# Je ne suis pas or Je suis pas?

Tags: grammaire, usage, négation

I have seen both of these phrases be used for "I am not:"

- Je suis pas
- Je ne suis pas

Also, when saying "*it* is not," the same dilemma arises:

- C'est pas
- Ce n'est pas

So, is it that they are used in different contexts? Or is one right and one is wrong? Or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Spoken French often drops *ne*. There have been already dozens of questions on this topic.

Comment: eg. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29526/when-is-ne-allowed-to-be-deleted-in-ne-plus/29528#29528