# "Ce livre a plus de quarante pages."

Tags: grammaire, sens, usage, comparatifs

Why not "Ce livre a plus que quarante pages."? Why "de" here instead of using "que"? I thought "que" translated to "than", and this sentence translates to "This book has more than forty pages", so why not use "que"?

Comment: Tough one. Both explaining and understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Both sentences are possible but with a potential difference in meaning. The first one is more common:

> *Ce livre a **plus de** quarante pages*

just states the fact the book has more than 40 pages. It is an approximation, not a comparison. The final *S* of *plus* is generally not pronounced.

> *Ce livre a **plus que** quarante pages*

might be contradicting a previous statement telling the book has (only) 40 pages. Unlike in the first sentence, a true comparison is made here between the number of pages of the book and the number 40:

> *Ce livre a **plus de** pages **que** quarante (pages)*.

If the expected meaning is the same than the first sentence (a statement, not a refutation), the register can be perceived as more colloquial.

Note that the final *S* of *plus* need to be pronounced in *plus que quarante page*. Otherwise, the meaning is "this book has only 40 pages left" (i.e. *ce livre [n']a plus que quarante pages* (*dans sa dernière édition* or *maintenant que tu en as arraché la moitié*).

See [this detailed answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/275/1109) about when to pronounce the final *s* of *plus*.

Answer (score 2):

*Ce livre **a plus que** quarante pages*

Formation classique d'un comparatif de supériorité. Plus est ici **adverbe**.
En tant que tel c'est au verbe qu'il se rapporte. Avoir plus, avoir davantage.

- Ce livre a davantage de pages que quarante.

*Ce livre a **plus de quarante pages***

Plus est ici **adjectif**.
En tant que tel il se rapporte à la quantité. C'est la quantité qui est supérieure.

- Le livre a des pages en quantité supérieure à 40

Avec un verbe comme *avoir* qui n'exprime pas particulièrement de process, les deux formulations portent rigoureusement le même sens.
Il en irait différemment avec d'autres verbes.

Littré prend son exemple avec *porter* :

*Ce cep portait plus que vingt grappes* C'est le port, l'effort de porter qui est plus important.

*Ce cep portait plus de vingt grappes* Le nombre de grappes était supérieur à vingt.

---

English traduction courtesy of @Laure

---

> *Ce livre **a plus que** quarante pages*

It's the usual way the comparative of superiority is built. In this case *plus* is an adverb and, as such, refers to the verb : it means *avoir plus* and *plus* is a synonym of *davantage*.

- Ce livre a davantage de pages que quarante.

> *Ce livre a **plus de quarante pages***

Plus is an **adjective** in this case, it refers to the amount of pages, the amount of pages is superior to 40.

With a verb like *avoir*, which shows no real process, both sentences have the same meaning, but it would not be the case with other verbs. This is the example we find in *Littré* :

*Ce cep portait plus que vingt grappes*  The stress is on the effort of carrying. The vine stock carried over twenty bunches of grapes.

*Ce cep portait plus de vingt grappes* The number of grapes was superior to twenty.

Comment: @Laure : Merci à toi! J'aurais décidément bien mauvaise grâce à corriger quoi que ce soit.