# Prononciation du mot « plus » dans la chanson « Ne me quitte pas » de Jacques Brel

Tags: prononciation, participe-présent, inversion

Bonjour à tous, je suis un Allemand en train d'apprendre le français. Dans la chanson « Ne me quitte pas » de Jacques Brel il y a quelque chose que je trouve remarquable et que je ne comprends pas vraiment. Le quatrième couplet commence par la phrase qui suit :

> On a vu souvent
>
> Rejaillir le feu
>
> D’un ancien volcan
>
> Qu’on croyait trop vieux
>
> Il est paraît-il
>
> Des terres brûlées
>
> Donnant plus de blé
>
> Qu’un meilleur avril

Ma question concerne la partie « *Il est paraît-il des terres brûlées donnant plus de blé* » qui veut dire, à ma compréhension, que les terres du volcan donnent plus de blé qu'un meilleur avril. Si cette « interpretation » de la phrase est correcte, je me demande :

**Pourquoi Jacques Brel ne prononce-t-il pas le « s » dans le mot « plus » ?**

Voir [la chanson sur YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2wmKcBm4Ik)

J'ai appris qu'il faut prononcer le « s » dans le mot « plus » quand il s'agit d'une comparaison positive qui se réfère à un substantif. Par exemple, dans la phrase

*Les terres du volcan donnent plus de blé qu'un meilleur avril*.

Donc la différence doit résulter du fait qu'on a le participe *donnant*  dans la chanson et le « plus » y réfère. Est-ce que cette interprétation est correcte ?

---

**Edit:** J'ai conscience de [cette question sur la prononciation de « plus »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/268/when-does-one-pronounce-the-s-in-plus?rq=1) qui dit qu'on ne prononce pas le « s » si « plus » est un adverbe. Mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi « plus » est un adverbe dans mon cas.

---

**2ème Edit:** En vue des réponses qui suggèrent que la prononciation de « plus » soit une figure de style de Jacques Brel ou une conséquence de son origine belge, je précise que la prononciation est la même dans toutes les autres versions de la chanson que j'ai trouvées sur YouTube:

[Johnny Hallyday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5p1ZoZfvPI)  (Parisien)

[Augustin Charnet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IWxKwMpMNY) (Toulousain)

[Wyclef Jean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HHBFkdHyRU)  (Haïtien)

[Céline Dion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQyonCHoJtc) (Canadienne)

[Maysa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfr5FHPXJQs) (Brasilienne)

[Nina Simone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Q7w7gk1JhQ) (Américaine)

[Franco Califano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tC_xKI9shI) (Italien)

[Yuri Buenaventura](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyPj1kandwg)  (Colombien)

Evidemment, le [plu] rime mieux avec *brûler*, peut-être c'est pour ça qu'on ne veut pas prononcer le « s ».

**Encore, je me demande si cette figure de style repousse vraiment les règles usuelles de la prononciation ou s'il reste la possibilité d'associer le « plus » au « donnant » pour réconcilier la figure de style avec les règles.**

Comment: La question liée est pourant assez claire. "Plus" est soit  une particule négative, soit à verbe conjugué, soit un nom (rare), soit un adverbe. Les explications sont assez claires pour identifier dans le cas présent un adverbe. Cela dit la prononciation du "s" dans ce cas ne m'aurait pas semblé incongrue (avis personnel).

Comment: — 2ème édit : Le choix de prononciation ne dépend pas du chanteur, mais de la musique, du rythme, des choix de l’auteur … essayez de le chanter avec « plusse » voire « plusseeuu » … la réponse n’est pas du domaine de la grammaire !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La compréhension se fait avec la phrase suivante, le *plus* est positif, tout bon grammairien prononcerait le *s* …

… mais … Jacques Brel est un poète authentique qui va chercher ses mots au fond de ses tripes …

… de surcroît, il est compositeur et chante ses œuvres.

Il y a donc licence poétique : le sens de *plus* ne pouvant porter le doute, pour l’harmonie mélodique et rythmique la suppression de la prononciation du *s* s’impose alors.

Answer (score 1):

Aussi d'un point de vu culturel, hors du sud de la France, beaucoup de gens prononce plus [plu] et moins [moin] et utilise le s uniquement lors des liaison, par exemple il est rare d'entendre les lyonnais dire [plus] (on entendra plus souvent [plu] par example la phrase "plus il y en a" sera prononcé [plu z'il y en a]) mais il est courant d'entendre les catalans (côté français) dire 'plus'. Jacques Brel quant a lui était belge.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas d’ambiguïté.

plus au sens négatif (donc sans 's') donnerais :

> Il est paraît-il des terres brûlées **ne** donnant plus de blé

Comment: Je ne pense pas que c'est le bon sense.